# Create a Wicket Quickstart maven

Tags: maven, wicket

I am trying to create Wicket with maven application followed by URL: http://wicket.apache.org/start/quickstart.html , but i get the following error, means the build is getting failed. please help me

executed the below command to generate application

mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.wicket -DarchetypeArtifactId=wicket-archetype-quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=1.5-SNAPSHOT -DgroupId=com.mycompany -DartifactId=myproject -DarchetypeRepository=https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/ -DinteractiveMode=false

The build is failed
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.wicket -DarchetypeArtifactId=wicket-archetype-quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=1.5-SNAPSHOT -DgroupId=com.mycompany -DartifactId=myproject -DarchetypeRepository=https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/ -DinteractiveMode=false

Comment: Error: Downloading: repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/… [WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plug in:2.4.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.4. 1

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with your Maven setup. This plugin is available in Maven central repo but for some reason it seems you don't have Central in your list of repos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for all responses, apparently the problem got resolved by just changing the proxy settings in maven setting.xml file.

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me with the **exact** command that *you* issued (shown here on multiple lines for clarity):

```
mvn archetype:generate 
    -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.wicket 
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=wicket-archetype-quickstart 
    -DarchetypeVersion=1.5-SNAPSHOT 
    -DgroupId=com.mycompany -DartifactId=myproject 
    -DarchetypeRepository=https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/ 
    -DinteractiveMode=false
```

My setup is :

```
Apache Maven 3.0.3
Java version: 1.6.0_29
```

Although your error doesn't *imply* a Maven version problem I would suggest using Maven 3.  It has been stable for a **long time** now.

Do you have direct access to the Internet (and therefore `repo1.maven.org`) or are you behind a proxy server? If so, does your settings file have the proxy configured?

Answer (score 1):

Dont use a SNAPSHOT archetype version unless you have the snapshot repository defined in your settings.xml. Use version 1.5.3 (see http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.wicket%7Cwicket-archetype-quickstart%7C1.5.3%7Cmaven-archetype) and forget about defining the archetypeRepository.

This works for me:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.wicket -DarchetypeArtifactId=wicket-archetype-quickstart  -DgroupId=com.mycompany -DartifactId=myproject -DinteractiveMode=false
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply, i still get the following error. build getting failed,, Do i need to use maven2 or Maven 3

Comment: the Error: Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.4.1/maven-clean-plugin-2.4.1.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plug
in:2.4.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.4.
1

Comment: I would suggest to use Maven 3 in any case. Maven 2 has many issues that will make things harder for you. Also are you behind a proxy or a repository server or something?

Answer (score 0):

Quickstarts are made from a Maven archetype. So, you will need to have Maven 2 installed and working (from the command line) before following this.

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.wicket -DarchetypeArtifactId=wicket-archetype-quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=6.4.0 -DgroupId=com.mycompany -DartifactId=myproject -DarchetypeRepository=https://repository.apache.org/ -DinteractiveMode=false
```

Results

This will produce the following project structure/files:

```
   .\myproject
    |   pom.xml
    |
    \---src
        +---main
        |   +---java
        |   |   \---com
        |   |       \---mycompany
        |   |               HomePage.html
        |   |               HomePage.java
        |   |               WicketApplication.java
        |   |
        |   +---resources
        |   |       log4j.properties
        |   |
        |   \---webapp
        |       \---WEB-INF
        |               web.xml
        |
        \---test
            \---java
                \---com
                    \---mycompany
                            Start.java
```